# Spark: How to convert RDD[(Long, Iterable[String])] to RDD[(Long, String)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to convert this RDD[(Long, Iterable[String])] to...

```
(852403,Set(PT0000094043, PT0000097083, PT0000036162))
(357331,Set(PT0000068829, PT0000094042, PT0000066859))
```

RDD[(Long, String)] like this ?

```
(852403, PT0000094043)
(852403, PT0000097083)
(852403, PT0000036162)
(357331, PT0000068829)
(357331, PT0000094042)
(357331, PT0000066859)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `flatMapValues`:

```
rdd.flatMapValues(identity)
```

or `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap{ case (k, vs) => vs.map(v => (k, v)) }
```